# How does mysql.proc table get entries?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

I want to know that in mysql when I create any procedure or function an entry for the corresponding create gets an entry in the mysql.proc table. I want to know by which process or trigger in mysql , It gets updated.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: ... And you are more likely to get answered in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables in the mysql database aren't tables in the sense that your application tables are.  Instead, they're internal mysql software data structures that happen to be made visible to the outside world as if they were tables.

So, the processes by which rows are made visible in those tables are entirely internal to the logic of mysqld.

Comment: Actually I made some changes in mysql.proc table i.e. DDL change. The corresponding data is required over there. Can we make some changes in the internal logic of mysql or in other words customization of mysqld. Is it possible.

Comment: As it is the internal logic of mysql , is it satic data or dynamic because I changes some data in mysql database and the data remain changed forever

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just get the source code to mysqld and change it.  But before you do that think about what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: Actually , My concern is related to view. whenever we create any function or procedure , its info i.e. definer info in stored in mysql.proc table but there is nothing similar to views , so I want to modify the mysqld which will also store the info about the view whenever its get created. Is it possible?

Comment: information_schema.views is a built in table that has information about views.

Comment: But we cannot modify the information schema. In mysql database I just need to update definer if it doesn`t exist in the restored server.